# Creating a dropdown submenu in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to know if it's possible to create a dropdown submenu in PowerPoint like the one for inserting a WordArt:

[image: The WordArt button]

If it's possible can you share with me some documentation about this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This a very unusual desire for a presentation. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What have you already researched and attempted? Please read [ask], then update your question with more details so we can try to help you.

Comment: Are you trying to alter the ribbon or put it in a slide?

Comment: Google this:  add gallery to office ribbon